# What technique I should use for this web UI feature? (HTML frame or table or others)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am not quite experienced with web UI design, so I ask here for some opinions of the UI feature I am currently working on. Basically, I would like to know which techniques I should use for the following feature:

I would like to implement a page, the left side of the page occupy 1/3 width of the page, and contain text field, buttons and checkboxes. The right side of the page occupy 2/3 width of the page, it will show some dynamic content based on the left side user input. The right side of the page is mainly implemented by using javascript, jQuery and ajax.

Should I use HTML frame for left and right sides of the page or should I just use a table to divide the page to two parts? or what else? which is better?

Comment: Introducing Cascading Style Sheets (CSS).

Answer (score 2):

You should use neither.

Instead, you should use a combination of the `<div>` tag for the markup and CSS to define the desired layout.

Comment: Any example or tutorial could you provide on how to use div & css for the layout design?

Comment: @Mellon - @Justin is absolutely right. As for a tutorial, I would recommend A List Apart. There is a bit of a learning curve, but they have some excellent tutorials. For your specific question, check out this tutorial: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/practicalcss/

Answer (score 1):

Never [ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever](http://www.mattheerema.com/web-design/2005/09/exactly-why-are-frames-bad/) use frames.

Comment: Perhaps, but not the urgency and seriousness of the matter.